# Fastest way to Read huge volume of data from DB

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a table which contains around 500 Million records. I am reading the data from table and  storing those in a Dictionary.

EDIT: I am loading the data into dictionary because these data needs to be compared with another volume of data coming from an indexing server.

My code is as below:

```
public static void GetDetailsFromDB()
{
    string sqlStr = "SELECT ID, Name ,Age, email ,DOB ,Address ,Affiliation ,Interest ,Homepage FROM Author WITH (NOLOCK) ORDER BY ID";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStr, _con);
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            //Author Class
            Author author = new Author();

            author.id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"].ToString());
            author.Name = reader["Name"].ToString().Trim();
            author.age = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Age"].ToString());
            author.email = reader["email"].ToString().Trim();
            author.DOB = reader["DOB"].ToString().Trim();
            author.Address = reader["Address"].ToString().Trim();
            author.Affiliation = reader["Affiliation"].ToString().Trim();
            author.Homepage = reader["Homepage"].ToString().Trim();

            string interests = reader["Interest"].ToString().Trim();
            author.interest = interests.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(p => p.Trim()).ToList();

            if (!AuthorDict.ContainsKey(author.id))
            {
                AuthorDict.Add(author.id, author);
            }

            if (AuthorDict.Count % 1000000 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}M author loaded.", AuthorDict.Count / 1000000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This process is taking long time to read and store all 500 Million records from DB. Also, the RAM usage is very high.

Can this be optimized ? also, can the running time be decreased ? any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you loading 500M records in RAM?

Comment: I need to compare the records with some other data.

Comment: So? You've got a database, those are good at searching for data. Please give more details about what you're trying to achieve if you want relevant answers.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(reader["Age"].ToString())` is a terrible anti- pattern.

Comment: Also, given your C# logic, you need to at least do some form of `DISTINCT` in your db query.

Comment: (and doing all that work just to throw it away if you have a duplicate ID can't help) - you didn't explain why you need to load that in memory, just why you think you do. Give more information about that other dataset.

Comment: @Mat, I just needed to fasten the process of reading the data from DB.   I hope, the question is totally valid and clear. I can't really get Why you need info about other dataset to fasten the process of reading data from DB.

Answer (score 3):

If I hold my nose I can come up with the following optimisations:

1. Store the ordinal positions of your fields in local variables and reference the fields in your `reader` using these ordinal variables.
2. Do not call `ToString` on the reader and convert - just get the value out in the correct type.
3. Check for the existence of the author id in the `AuthorDict` as soon as you have the id. Don't even create the `Author` instance if you don't need it.

   ```
   using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {
       var idOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("ID");
       //extract other ordinal positions and store here

       while (reader.Read())
       {
           var id = reader.GetInt32(idOrdinal);

           if (!AuthorDict.ContainsKey(id))
           {
               Author author = new Author();
               author.id = reader.GetInt32(idOrdinal);
               ...
           }
       }
   }
   ```